# jquery validate- add url methode with regex to allow url without http

Tags: jquery, regex, client-side-validation

I have a form running with jquery validate. The url methode they are using require http to be added to the url, and I want to allow users to submit url without http and or www. I used add methode:

```
   jQuery.validator.addMethod("urlRegex", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^(?:([a-z]+):(?:([a-z]*):)?\/\/)?(?:([^:@]*)(?::([^:@]*))?@)?((?:[a-z0-9_-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}|localhost|(?:(?:[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:(?:[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])))(?::(\d+))?(?:([^:\?\#]+))?(?:\?([^\#]+))?(?:\#([^\s]+))?$/.test(value);
    }, "PLEASE ENTER A VAILD WEBSITE ");
```

and under the rules I added the new method:

```
rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },

            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },

            website: {
                required: true,
                urlRegex: true
            },
         }
```

But it's still require http:\ at the beginning of the url. I checked this regex at regex101.com and it matches with urls such as example.com so I'm not sure if the problem is with the regex or with something else.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead...

This will work with or without HTTP://

```
/^([\:\/\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks. As iv'e wrote in the question, I need this to also work without www.(example.com should be valid). The regex I have  is working fine when I test it, so I don't think the problem is there.